# error message "The public type StackWithLinkedList must be defined in its own file"

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new here, thought I'd give this a shot. I am currently having trouble with my compiler in which I'm working with linked lists. I keep getting an error message, saying it needs it own file? Can anyone help me, I'm using Eclipse neon to code this problem thanks in advance here's the code.

```
class Node {

    int value;
    Node nextNode;

    Node(int v, Node n)

        {
        value = v;
        nextNode = n;
        }

    Node(int v)

    {
        this(v, null);

    }

}


    class Stack

{
        protected Node top;

        Stack() 

            {
                top = null;
            }


        boolean isEmpty()

            {
                return ( top == null );
            }



        void push (int v)

            {
                Node tempPointer;

                 tempPointer = new Node(v);

                tempPointer.nextNode = top;

                top = tempPointer;  
            }


        int pop ()

            {
                int tempValue;

                tempValue = top.value;

                top = top.nextNode;

                return tempValue;

            }



        void printStack()

            {
                Node aPointer = top;

                String tempString = "";


                while(aPointer != null)


                    {
                        tempString = tempString + aPointer.value + "\n";

                        aPointer = aPointer.nextNode;
                    }

                        System.out.println(tempString);

            }

}


        public class StackWithLinkedList 

            {
                public static void main(String[] args)

                    {
                        int popValue;

                        Stack myStack = new Stack();

                        myStack.push(5);
                        myStack.push(7);
                        myStack.push(9);

                        myStack.printStack();

                        popValue = myStack.pop();
                        popValue = myStack.pop();

                        myStack.printStack();

                    }

            }
```

Comment: You are trying to define more than one top-level class in a single source file. This is not allowed, and each top-level class must go in its own file.

Comment: would i have to do it as a interface my teacher doesn't help much and i've been self teaching myself but he uses jgrasp to code not eclipse

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to define more than one top-level class in a single source file. This is not allowed, and each top-level class must go in its own file. If you want to put everything in a single file the classes must be nested, as in

```
public class Test {
    ....
    public static class Node {
        ...
    }
    public static class Stack {
        ...
    }
    public static class StackWithLinkedList {
        ...
    }
}
```